# Wait for all handlers of a given event to complete

Tags: javascript, async-await, event-handling, dom-events, dispatchevent

I am writing a Javascript library and I would like to know if it is possible to do the following.

I want to trigger a custom event on an element, but I don't know *a priori* which event handler(s) have been subscribed to this event, nor how many.
Then, I would like to wait for all these event handlers to complete and then check if any of them has perform a given action (e.g. "reject" the event). If not, then the function that triggers the event shall proceed.

To be clear, I can provide arguments to the event handler(s), such as a "() => reject()" function, or define any sort of "contract" for the event handler, but I cannot modify the code that subscribes the event handler(s). Such code would be written by the users of the library.

Is this possible / desirable?

Thanks!

**Update**

Here is an example of code snipper I would like to use, consider that library end-user would essentially call addEventListener() or $.on() by themselves

```
$body = $("body")
function rejectEvent(o) {
    o.reject();
}
function acceptEvent(o) {}
function triggerEvent() {
    let isRejected = false;
    $body.trigger('custom-event', {
        reject: () => isRejected = true;
    });
    // Wait for all event handlers to complete...
    if (isRejected) {
         console.log('stop');
    } else {
         console.log('proceed');
    }
}

triggerEvent(); // Should display 'proceed'
$body.on('custom-event', function(e, o) {
    console.log('do nothing');
});
triggerEvent(); // Should display 'do nothing' then 'proceed'
$body.on('custom-event', function(e, o) {
    console.log('reject');
    o.reject();
});
triggerEvent(); // Should display 'do nothing' then 'reject' then 'stop'
$body.off('custom-event');
$body.on('custom-event', async function(e, o) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('reject');
        o.reject();
    }, 5000);
});
triggerEvent(); // Should display 'proceed' then 'reject'
```

As shown by this example, I can correctly retrieve the reject status of the event handlers as long as the event handlers are executed synchronously (at least that what I understood from googling this topic).
However, the main issue I have is if the end-user defines the event handlers as asynchronous.

So far, the best option I can see is to document that async event handlers are not supported, but I would love to be able to support them as well.

Comment: What kind of events are you talking about? DOM events? A node.js `EventEmitter`? Some other event library? Something custom?

Comment: Yes, providing a reject function to the event handler as part of the event is a good idea. Then it's on the subscribers to call that.

Comment: It would a custom event, but you can consider that it is a standard DOM event. I don't think it would make a difference, would it?

Comment: You mean a custom DOM event? On an [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget)?

Comment: Since the OP can neither change nor control how handlers get subscribed to element and event type, the OP could change the element‘s **addEventListener** method in a way that allows the interception of a listener‘s registration. Thus one could collect any handler function. I still need to think about how to detect/trace each of the handlers‘ invocation.

Comment: Since it looks like the OP writes and provides kind of a custom-event based API, could the OP provide a code example (not the library implementation) of what the OP describes as ... _"I can provide arguments to the event handler(s), such as a "() => reject()" function, or define any sort of "contract" for the event handler, "_ ... where one gets an idea of the library's purpose and an idea about it's usage as a third party member?

Comment: I added a code example to the question. Hopefully, this is clearer now.

Comment: @PeterSeliger changing the addEventListener method sounds interesting. I guess it could make sense to do that and try to wrap the end-user event handlers (which may be async) within a synchronous function and ensure the user event handlers completes before the wrapper function terminates. Will give it some thoughts, but I welcome more advice.

Comment: Actually, one issue with overriding addEventListener method is that I am sure I can control whether this is one before the end-user event handlers are added or not, given how the library is setup... :(

Comment: The half sentence ... _"end-user event handlers (which may be async) within a synchronous function"_ ... makes me wonder whether one should mix classic (**fire and forget**) event handling with promises and/or async await syntax. Actually until now I never encountered any promised/asynchronous event handler. In case one mixes the latter (asynchronous event handler functions) with dispatching custom events, one either has to replace the prototypal `dispatchEvent` with an own async function based implementation or one has to come up with an own prototypal extra method for it.

Comment: @PeterSeliger https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ExtendableEvent

Comment: @Bergi ... thanks, I have to read it carefully. I was totally not aware of the development/progress of the WebAPI.

Comment: @PeterSeliger IIRC it's only used in web workers, and there's no nice way to dispatch such an event yourself - but the pattern does exist

Answer (score 0):

From the above comments ...

> *"@PeterSeliger changing the addEventListener method sounds interesting. I guess it could make sense to do that and try to wrap the end-user event handlers (which may be async) within a synchronous function and ensure the user event handlers completes before the wrapper function terminates. Will give it some thoughts, but I welcome more advice." – syl*
>
> > The half sentence ... *"end-user event handlers (which may be async) within a synchronous function"* ... makes me wonder whether one should mix classic (**fire and forget**) event handling with promises and/or async await syntax. Actually until now I never encountered any promised/asynchronous event handler. In case one mixes the latter (asynchronous event handler functions) with dispatching custom events, one either has to replace the prototypal `dispatchEvent` with an own async function based implementation or one has to come up with an own prototypal extra method for it. – Peter Seliger

And of cause it can be done.

One would start with an intercepting approach for `HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener` where one would wrap additional functionality around the original implementation. Thus one later is capable to also control the dispatching of custom events by either replacing `HTMLElement.prototype.dispatchEvent` with an own implementation or comes up with a custom e.g. `HTMLElement.prototype.dispatchMonitoredEvent` method or, even better, in case one entirely controls the dispatching environment, one implements it as just to the lib-author accessible `dispatchMonitoredEvent` method.

As for the interception approach. One does this in order to store **element-node specific *listeners*** in a (maybe even globally accessible) `listenerStorage` which is a [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) instance which, based on node references, holds **each node's *listener* [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)** instance. The latter features event-type specific entries, where one can access the **handler-array value** by an **event-type key**.

```js
function handleFormControlEvent({ type: eventType, currentTarget: node }) {
  console.log({
    node,
    nodeValue: node.value,
    eventType,
  });
}
function logFormControlHandlerCount({ type: eventType, currentTarget: node }) {
  console.log({
    [ `${ eventType }HandlerCount` ]: listenerStorage
      .get(node)
      .get(eventType)
      .length
  });
}
function logCheckboxState({ currentTarget: { checked } }) {
  console.log({ checked });
}

document
  .querySelectorAll('input')
  .forEach(elmNode => {
    elmNode.addEventListener('input', handleFormControlEvent);
    elmNode.addEventListener('input', logFormControlHandlerCount);
  });
document
  .querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]')
  .forEach(elmNode => {
    elmNode.addEventListener('click', handleFormControlEvent);
    elmNode.addEventListener('click', logCheckboxState);
    elmNode.addEventListener('click', logFormControlHandlerCount);
  });

document
  .querySelector('[type="checkbox"]')
  .dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('click'));
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
fieldset { width: 40%; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 4px 4px; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; min-height: 100%!important; width: 58%; }
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>test area</legend>
  <label>
    <span>Foo:</span>
    <input type="text" value="Foo" />
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Bar:</span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </label>
</fieldset>

<script>
HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener = (function (proceed) {
  window.listenerStorage = storage = new WeakMap;

  return function addEventListener(type, handler) {
    const currentTarget = this;

    let listeners = storage.get(currentTarget);
    if (!listeners) {
      listeners = new Map;
      storage.set(currentTarget, listeners);
    }
    let handlerList = listeners.get(type);
    if (!handlerList) {
      handlerList = [];
      listeners.set(type, handlerList);
    }
    if (!handlerList.includes(handler)) {
      handlerList.push(handler)
    }
    // proceed with delegation to the original implementation.
    proceed.call(currentTarget, type, handler);
  };
}(HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener));
</script>
```

The monitoring depends on either handler functions which have to return a value (which is not the classic handler function way) from which one could tell failure/success or on return values of resolved/settled async handler functions (which is even more unusual). Building on the above example code, the implementation and usage of a non/prototypal async `dispatchMonitoredEvent` function/method could look like follows ...

```js
function handleFormControlEvent({ type: eventType, currentTarget: node }) {
  console.log({
    node,
    nodeValue: node.value,
    eventType,
  });
  // function statement as event handler, but with unusual return value.
  return { controlEventSuccess: true };
}
function logFormControlHandlerCount({ type: eventType, currentTarget: node }) {
  console.log({
    [ `${ eventType }HandlerCount` ]: listenerStorage
      .get(node)
      .get(eventType)
      .length
  });
  // function statement as event handler, but with unusual return value.
  return { handlerCountSuccess: true };
}
async function logCheckboxState({ currentTarget: { checked } }) {
  // asynchronous function as event handler.
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => {

      console.log({ checked });
      resolve({ checkboxStateSuccess: true });

    }, 2000)
  );
}

document
  .querySelectorAll('input')
  .forEach(elmNode => {
    elmNode.addEventListener('input', handleFormControlEvent);
    elmNode.addEventListener('input', logFormControlHandlerCount);
  });
document
  .querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]')
  .forEach(elmNode => {
    elmNode.addEventListener('click', handleFormControlEvent);
    elmNode.addEventListener('click', logCheckboxState);
    elmNode.addEventListener('click', logFormControlHandlerCount);
  });

document
  .querySelector('[type="checkbox"]')
  .dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('click'));

console.log(
  '\n+++ dispatched monitored custom events +++\n\n'
);

(async function () {

  console.log(
    '... trigger ... execute all at once and log at the end ...'
  );
  // execute all at once ...
  Promise
    .all([
      document
        .querySelector('[type="checkbox"]')
        .dispatchMonitoredEvent(new CustomEvent('click')),
      document
        .querySelector('input')
        .dispatchMonitoredEvent(new CustomEvent('input')),
    ])
    // ... and log at the end.
    .then(values =>
      values.forEach(returnValues =>

        console.log({ returnValues })
      )
    );

  console.log(
    '... trigger ... execute and log one after the other ...'
  );
  // execute and log one after the other.
  let returnValues = await document
    .querySelector('[type="checkbox"]')
    .dispatchMonitoredEvent(new CustomEvent('click'));

  console.log({ returnValues });

  returnValues = await document
    .querySelector('input')
    .dispatchMonitoredEvent(new CustomEvent('input'));

  console.log({ returnValues });

})();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
fieldset { width: 40%; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 4px 4px; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; min-height: 100%!important; width: 58%; }
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>test area</legend>
  <label>
    <span>Foo:</span>
    <input type="text" value="Foo" />
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Bar:</span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </label>
</fieldset>

<script>
HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener = (function (proceed) {
  window.listenerStorage = storage = new WeakMap;

  return function addEventListener(type, handler) {
    const currentTarget = this;

    let listeners = storage.get(currentTarget);
    if (!listeners) {
      listeners = new Map;
      storage.set(currentTarget, listeners);
    }
    let handlerList = listeners.get(type);
    if (!handlerList) {
      handlerList = [];
      listeners.set(type, handlerList);
    }
    if (!handlerList.includes(handler)) {
      handlerList.push(handler)
    }
    // proceed with delegation to the original implementation.
    proceed.call(currentTarget, type, handler);
  };
}(HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener));

async function dispatchMonitoredEvent({
  isTrusted =false, bubbles = false,
  cancelBubble = false, cancelable = false,
  composed = false, defaultPrevented = false,
  detail = null, eventPhase = 0, path = [],
  returnValue = true, timeStamp = Data.now(),
  type = null,
}) {
  // @TODO ... custom event data handling/copying is in need of improvement.
  const currentTarget = this;
  const monitoredEvent = {
    isTrusted, bubbles, cancelBubble, cancelable, composed, currentTarget,
    defaultPrevented, detail, eventPhase, path, returnValue,
    srcElement: currentTarget, target: currentTarget,
    timeStamp, type,
  };
  const handlerList = listenerStorage
    .get(currentTarget)
    ?.get(type) ?? [];

  return (await Promise
    .all(
      handlerList
        .map(handler =>
          handler(monitoredEvent)
          // (async (evt) => handler(evt))(monitoredEvent)
        )
    ));
};
HTMLElement
  .prototype
  .dispatchMonitoredEvent = dispatchMonitoredEvent;
</script>
```

***Edit***

Having learned from the above approach and implementation and taking now the OP's later provided example code into account, one could come up with an implementation for ***custom cancelable events*** where the entire `async...await` handling is build around a custom event's augmented `detail` property.

Thus, regardless of having registered normal/classic or async handler functions, one does not change a handlers arity (the amount of a function's expected / to be handled arguments) but does control the cancellation of a dispatch process by setting e.g. the sole event-argument's `detail.proceed` property to `false`.

All of an element's registered event-type specific handler function's will be processed by an async generator which controls a functions execution and has access to the current event object's reference. Based on either failing/rejected handler functions or on the current `event.detail.proceed` value, the async generator continues/stops yielding.

The asynchronous `dispatchCustomCancelableEvent` method which operates the generator does return an object which carries all relevant data, like `success`, `canceled`, `error` and `event`, about the settled dispatch process. And `event.detail` provides additional information about the involved `handlers` and the `cancelHandler` (the handler which was responsible for any kind of cancelation).

```js
async function triggerTestEvent(elmNode) {
  const result = await elmNode
    .dispatchCustomCancelableEvent('custom-cancelable-event');

  const { /*event, success, */canceled/*, error = null*/ } = result;

  // in order to meet the OP's requirement of ...
  // ... "Wait for all event handlers to complete"
  if (canceled) {
    console.log('stop', { result });
  } else {
    console.log('proceed', { result });
  }
}

(async () => {
  const testNode = document.querySelector('div');

  // should display 'proceed'.
  await triggerTestEvent(testNode); 

  testNode
    .addEventListener('custom-cancelable-event', () =>
      console.log('do nothing')
    );
  // should display 'do nothing' then 'proceed'.
  await triggerTestEvent(testNode);

  testNode
    .addEventListener('custom-cancelable-event', evt => {
      console.log('reject');
      evt.detail.proceed = false; // was ... o.reject();
    });
  testNode
    .addEventListener('custom-cancelable-event', () =>
      console.log('+++ should never be displayed +++')
    );
  // should display 'do nothing' then 'reject' then 'stop'
  await triggerTestEvent(testNode);


  testNode
    .removeCustomListeners('custom-cancelable-event');

  testNode
    .addEventListener('custom-cancelable-event', (/*evt*/) =>
      console.log('... handle event ...')
    );
  testNode
    .addEventListener('custom-cancelable-event', async (evt) =>
      new Promise((resolve/*, reject*/) =>
        setTimeout(() => {

          console.log('... cancle event ...');
          // reject('cancle event');

          evt.detail.proceed = false; // was ... o.reject();
          resolve();

        }, 5000)
      )
    );
  testNode
    .addEventListener('custom-cancelable-event', () =>
      console.log('+++ should never be displayed +++')
    );
  // should display
  // '... handle event ...' then '... cancle event ...' then 'stop'
  await triggerTestEvent(testNode); 

})();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; min-height: 100%!important; width: 80%; }
```

```html
<div>dispatch test node</div>

<script>
HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener = (function (proceed) {
  window.listenerStorage = storage = new WeakMap;

  return function addEventListener(type, handler) {
    const currentTarget = this;

    let listeners = storage.get(currentTarget);
    if (!listeners) {
      listeners = new Map;
      storage.set(currentTarget, listeners);
    }
    let handlerList = listeners.get(type);
    if (!handlerList) {
      handlerList = [];
      listeners.set(type, handlerList);
    }
    if (!handlerList.includes(handler)) {
      handlerList.push(handler)
    }
    // proceed with delegation to the original implementation.
    proceed.call(currentTarget, type, handler);
  };
}(HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener));

HTMLElement.prototype.removeCustomListeners =
  function removeCustomListeners (type) {
    storage
      .get(this)
      ?.delete?.(type);
  };

HTMLElement.prototype.dispatchCustomCancelableEvent = (function () {
  async function* createCancelableDispatchablesPool(handlerList, evt) {
    handlerList = [...handlerList];

    let isProceed = true;
    let handler;
    let recentHandler;

    while (isProceed && (handler = handlerList.shift())) {
      try {
        if (evt.detail.proceed === true) {
          recentHandler = handler;

          yield (await handler(evt));
        } else {
          evt.detail.proceed = isProceed = false;
          evt.detail.cancelHandler = recentHandler;
        }
      } catch (reason) {
        // an (async) handler function's execution
        // could also just fail with or without reason.
        evt.detail.proceed = isProceed = false;
        evt.detail.cancelHandler = recentHandler;

        yield (
          new Error(String(reason ?? 'failed without reason'))
        );
      }
    }
  }
  return async function dispatchCustomCancelableEvent(type, options = {}) {
    const currentTarget = this;

    const handlerList = listenerStorage
      .get(currentTarget)
      ?.get(type) ?? [];

    Object.assign((options.detail ??= {}), {

      currentTarget,
      target: currentTarget,

      // extend a custom event's `detail`
      // by a boolean `proceed` property.
      // and a list of all event `handlers`.
      proceed: true,
      handlers: handlerList,
    });
    const customEvent = new CustomEvent(type, options);

    const dispatchablesPool =
      createCancelableDispatchablesPool(handlerList, customEvent);

    const dispatchResult = {
      success: true,
      canceled: true,
    };
    for await (const result of dispatchablesPool) {
      // an (async) handler function's execution
      // could also just fail with or without reason.
      if (result instanceof Error) {
        dispatchResult.success = false;
        dispatchResult.error = result;
      }
    }
    if (customEvent.detail.proceed === true) {

      dispatchResult.canceled = false;

    } else if (!customEvent.detail.cancelHandler) {

      customEvent.detail.cancelHandler =
        // customEvent.detail.handlers.at(-1)
        customEvent.detail.handlers.slice(-1)[0];
    }
    return Object.assign(dispatchResult, { event: customEvent });
  };
}());
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a quite involved solution and example, but I understand that it starts by overwriting the HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener() method, and this would need to be done before the end-user starts adding event listeners to DOM elements, and I'm just not sure I can do that.
But I will explore this approach anyway to see what I can do.

Comment: @syl ... There is another implementation which takes your provided example code into account.